# How many solutions $Ax=0$ has

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

### Problem

How many solutions equation $Ax=0$ has when $A$ is defined as:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 1 & 4 & 0 \\ -4 & 2  & 1 \end{bmatrix}  $$

### Attemtp to solve

One way would be to solve this problem with row reduction and see how many solutions equation has. Another way would be to compute determinant since, it tells if linear transformation squishes all possible vectors to a line.

$$ \det(A)=95 $$

It looks like this linear transformation doesn't squish everything to single line. Ax=0 will only have trivial solution of $x=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^T$. When determinant is $0$ equation $Ax=0$ has infinite amount of solutions. Linear transformation squishes a whole line of vectors to $0$ meaning $Ax=0$ has full line of solutions or infinite amount.

I would like to know if this intuition is correct or am I missing something or perhaps just simply wrong ?

Comment: Your intuition is right, as long as equation is $Av=0.$ When nonzero on right, sometimes no solution.

Comment: @coffeemath Your comment is somewhat misleading.  Note that this is a square matrix (otherwise OP couldn't compute the determinant).  $Ax = y$ has the solution $x = A^{-1} y$.  For **non-square** matrices it is possible that $Ax = 0$ has only one solution and $Ax  = y$ has no solutions for some $y$.

Comment: The rank of the matrix $A$ is the codimension of the subspace of solutions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael When $A$ is square and $\det(A)=0,$ and right side $b \neq 0,$ for some such $A,b$ pairs no solution, for others infinitely many. OP already remarked det zero case with zero on right has infinitely many solutions, I was just noting if right side nonzero with det zero there may be infinitely many or no solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.  A square matrix $A$ whose determinant is nonzero is invertible, and then the equation $Ax = y$ always has a unique solution.

Comment: Indeed if it had $2$ solutions $Au=y$ and $Av=y \implies A(u-v)=0,\, u-v\neq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$Ax=0$ may not only have a line of solutions,  it may have a plane, or, in the case of the zero transformation,  the whole three dimensional space.

In general,  the null space will have dimension $3-\operatorname{rank}A$, by the Rank-nullity theorem.